# How to use `Optional.ofNullable(variable)` in java 7 version

Tags: java

Is there another way to take `Optional.ofNullable(variable)` in java 7. `Optional.ofNullable(variable)` is considered  java 8 version but it is not working on java 7 version. How can i take `Optional.ofNullable(vaiable)` in java 7 version anyone could you please tell me

When i place the cursor in `Optional.ofNullable(variable)` it shows like this image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Optional in github](https://github.com/koher/Java7-Optional/blob/master/src/org/koherent/util/Optional.java) or other [suggestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/2egoxa/java_7_backports_for_javautiloptional/)

Answer (score 0):

Guava library contains Options implementation, java 7 supported until 21 version: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html